# Unknown syntax [[:Book:{{{Pages}}}|Pages]] and the purpose thereof

Tags: angularjs, syntax, expression

I saw an expression, which looks like an AngularJS expression on a web site recently and I've been trying to find out exactly what the purpose of it is, by trying to replicate this in NG, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

The syntax was similar to:

```
[[:Book:{{{Pages}}}|Pages]]
```

Has anyone seen a syntax like this and know what it represents?

Comment: Why do you think it's angular? Post context of that snippet. Where did you see it?

Comment: Because it follows the Angular filter express rule, e.g the "|" and the expression brackets before it {{Pages}}. I didn't save a link to the site, just copied the code and tested it in an angular app :$

Comment: It doesn't follow the rule. Example: `{{ my.model | filter }}`. This doesn't seem like Angular.

Comment: @JadedEric: you might be surprised, but `|` token is used in a **lots** of places and contexts, not only angular filters.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's the first thing I tried, but it didn't work in angular, and now I just have to find where this comes from :$. I'm trying to look for the page source I grabbed this from, will post when I get it.